# Phonegap IOS PrintPlugin for Cordova 2.0 

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

hi iam working in phonegap IOS (cordova 2.0) i need a print Plugin and i found only one plugin that not supporting 2.0 [- link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PrintPlugin)
only support up to cordova 1.5. anybody please  help me , is there any PrintPlugin that support cordova 2.0.

Can anyone help  ? ?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. If anyone has a way to do this I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this writing, the PrintPlugin from the GitHub repository is targeted at Cordova 1.5.  If you get that version, and make the following changes, you can compile within a Cordova 2.0 Project.

NOTICE: I have seen a bug in this entire plugin which is an issue with printing more than one page.  I have found that it is related to a lack of logic to wait for the webView to complete load before printing.  I am currently working a a new version of this plugin to allow for custom headers, page numbering etc.  But for now.....   ;)

In the current repository .m file, it has the following function declaration:

```
- (void) print:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options{
    NSUInteger argc = [arguments count];

    if (argc < 1) {
        return; 
    }
    self.printHTML = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];

  ... << snipped />> ... 


    [self doPrint];
}
```

This is followed with a separate doPrint function.

```
- (void) doPrint{
    if (![self isPrintServiceAvailable]){
        [self callbackWithFuntion:self.failCallback withData: @"{success: false, available: false}"];

        return;
    }

    UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

      if (!controller){
          return;
      }

        ... << snipped  (cut and paste to below) />> ...
}
```

I updated my local copy and merged the two into a single function, and utilized a different mechanism for obtaining the arguments.  Following is my .m function declaration:

```
- (void) print:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options
{   
    // NSUInteger argc = [arguments count];

    NSString* printHTML = [options valueForKey:@"printHTML"];
    NSString* successCallback = [options valueForKey:@"success"];
    NSString* failCallback = [options valueForKey:@"fail"];
    NSString* dialogLeftPos = [options valueForKey:@"dialogLeftPos"];
    NSString* dialogTopPos = [options valueForKey:@"dialogTopPos"];


  UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

  if (!controller){
      return;
  }

    ... <<  snipped (paste the rest from your original block here />> ...
}
```

I then also modified the .JS to create an object instead of simply the parameter list.

The current repository PrintPlugin.js has:

```
return Cordova.exec("PrintPlugin.print", printHTML, callbackPrefix + '.success', callbackPrefix + '.fail', dialogLeftPos, dialogTopPos);
```

return Cordova.exec("PrintPlugin.print", printHTML, callbackPrefix + '.success', callbackPrefix + '.fail', dialogLeftPos, dialogTopPos);

I changed this to the following:

```
var args = {
    'printHTML': printHTML,
    'success': callbackPrefix + '.success',
    'fail': callbackPrefix + '.fail', 
    'dialogLeftPos': dialogLeftPos,
    'dialogTopPos': dialogTopPos
};

cordova.exec(null, null, "PrintPlugin", "print", [args]);
```

Now, it may turn out that I could have simply changed the case in the Cordova to cordova, but that is pure hindsight.  Either way, I hope this helps!

Comment: Ummm...  sorry, I thought that I did answer the question pretty directly.

Comment: Specifically....  Get the current PrintPlugin from the repository (which works with Cordova 1.5).  Make the changes that I specified above.  Compile under Cordova 2.0 Project.  You now have a Cordova 2.0 compatible PrintPlugin.

Comment: Sorry Tyler, I misunderstood.  :)

Comment: has there been an update for cordova 3.x yet? anybody working on one?